# how combine multiple arrays into a single associate array using the arrays as keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have 2 arrays that i would like to loop through and combine into an associative array. I would like to use the 2 arrays as the keys for the new associative array. I am new to php so any and all help would be appreciated.

```
$id = array( 2, 4);

$qty = array( 5, 7);

array('id' => , 'qty' => );
```

Thanks in advance

I would like to output something like this

```
array(
'id' => 2,
'qty' => 5),
array(
'id'=> 4,
'qty' => 7
)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be? `array('id' => array(2, 4), 'qty' => array(5, 7) )`?

Comment: Interpreting your question literally, you cannot use an array as a key. A key must be a scalar value — a string or integer, essentially.

Comment: $newArray = array('id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty); ???

Comment: `array('id' => , 'qty' => )` is invalid; please provide a valid expression.

Comment: I just edited the question with what i would like to output array to look like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
$result = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++) {
  $result[] = array('id' => $id[$i], 'qty' => $qty[$i]);
}
```

---

Added by Mchl:
Alternative, IMHO a bit clearer, but it's matter of opinion mostly

```
$result = array();

foreach($id as $key => $value) {
  $result[] = array('id' => $id[$key], 'qty' => $qty[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also one-liner w/ lambda (PHP >= 5.3.0) and short array syntax `[]` (PHP >= 5.4)

```
$combined = array_map(function($id, $qty) {return ['id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty];}, $id, $qty);
```

or callback and old `array()` for earlier versions

```
function comb($id, $qty)
{
    return array('id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty);
}
$combined = array_map('comb', $id, $qty);
```